# explaination on a few python scripts

Tags: python

I just started to learn python to parse some variant calling format (VCF). A brief file format is like this (From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Call_Format)):

The line I saw from [here](https://github.com/brantp/rtd/blob/master/vcf_to_rqtl.py) is:

```
alleles = set(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[re.split('[/|]',v['GT']) for v in indiv_gt.values()]))
    if len(alleles) == 1:
        return 0
    if len(alleles) > 2:
        return None
```

I am struggling to understand this "alleles = ..."

My understanding is first iterate the values in the dictionary indiv_gt, the values would be a bunch of genotypes like "1/1" or "2/2" or "1/0".

Then re.split will catch the these genotype contains "/" "|" and split, so that 1/1 will become 1, 1, 1/0 will become 1/0, so on and so forth. But i am not quite sure, should not "|" have a different meaning in the regular expression, if it is used, it should come with an escape sign, i would think it would be something like "/\|" in the search pattern, why a [ ] here in the search pattern ?

Then came a reduce lambda function, does it intend to join all of "0s, 1s, 2s" after split ted? or arithmetically add those 0s, 1s, and 2s up?

Finally use the set function, so only unique characters will be saved at the end.

This would make sense, because if all characters are just 0s, or 1s or 2s, then this will return 0

I hope my question make a bit sense to y'all. Quite confused right now.

Best,

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, i did my homework, just wanted some comments if my understanding is correct. sorry, i have to clarify i did not write this line, thats why i really want to know if i understand this correctly.

Comment: The lambda is just a plain addition and could alternatively be written as `def f(x, y): return x+y`. The `|` in the RE doesn't need to be escaped as it's inside of `[]` which denotes a literal range of characters; the expression matches either `/` or `|`. You could have learned this by reading the documentation of python's `re` library as well as the tutorial on lambdas.

Comment: Irrelevant aside: I think there's no need to split the strings then join them back up just to get rid of `/|`, instead put them all into one long string right away, replace the `/|` out of it, then make a set from it. `set(re.sub('[/|]','',''.join([v['GT'] for v in indiv_gt.values()])))` to save _13_ whole characters (untested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in a regular expression the character `|` means "or", but only when used outside a character subset. Inside brackets it simply mean itself and requires no escaping. Writing `[/|]` means just "either `|` or `/`".
2. `reduce` will start with `x` equal to the first element of the sequence and then will repeatedly execute `x = f(x, y)` where `f` is the reduce function argument. In Python the `+` operator can work with both numbers (adding) or strings (concatenating). This means that reducing a list of strings with `lambda x,y:x+y` will concatenate them and reducing a list of numbers will compute the sum instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, should have done more homework before posting this,best.